# Custom dict with hashable keys cannot handle recursive structures

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hash, hashmap

I need a dictionary-like structure that can take unhashable keys and map them to a value. I need this for two reasons:

1. Checking if an item has already been seen in *O(1)* when traversing a list
2. Mapping each item to an identifier, by example a character

The created dict-like structure would be thrown away after the process so it cannot be used once keys can be mutated.

#### Example

```
d = MutableKeyDict()

d[[1, 2, 3]] = 'a'

print([1, 2, 3] in d)  # True
print((1, 2, 3) in d)  # False
```

## Implementation

*tl;dr I implemented something that does not work. If you see a canonical way to implement this, skip that part.*

For now, I wrote a wrapper class that implements a `__hash__` method that falls back on the immutable type equivalent to hash its data.

```
class ForcedHashable:
    @staticmethod
    def hashable(obj):
        try:
            hash(obj)
            return obj
        except TypeError:
            if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
                return tuple(ForcedHashable.hashable(o) for o in obj)
            elif isinstance(obj, set):
                return frozenset(ForcedHashable(o) for o in obj)
            elif isinstance(obj, dict):
                return tuple((k, ForcedHashable.hashable(v)) for k, v in obj.items())
            ...

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.data == other.data

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.hashable(self.data))
```

This allowed me to write a draft of a custom dict class that uses the `ForcedHashable` to wrap its keys.

```
class MutableKeyDict(UserDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[ForcedHashable(key)] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data[ForcedHashable(item)]

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return ForcedHashable(item) in self.data
```

It works for the basic cases...

```
d = MutableKeyDict()

d[[1, 2, 3]] = 'a'

print([1, 2, 3] in d)  # True
print((1, 2, 3) in d)  # False
```

But encounters some issues with objects nested in themselves.

```
d = MutableKeyDict()

x = []
x.append(x)

d[x] = 'foo' # raises a 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'
```

The recursion of course originate from that statement:

```
if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
    return tuple(ForcedHashable.hashable(o) for o in obj)
```

I was half-way through implementing a fix with a `memo`, kind of like the one `copy.deepcopy` uses, but then I realized that even if I do, this method too will raise a `RecursionError`.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.data == other.data
```

## Question

I would want the above to at least work for the builtin types.

Would there be a clever way to go around that `RecursionError`? And if not, is there a canonical way to associate equal items (builtin types only) to a temporary hash? Other approaches are more than welcome.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, the memo will work. I just stopped the implementation because I don't know if I can avoid the self.data == other.data line infinite recursion.

Comment: But that `__eq__` already does work even with a single level of recursion, right? I mean, as soon as you compare a `ForcedHashable.__eq__(list)`, you're going to get an `AttributeError` on `list.data`.

Comment: What exact semantics are you looking for? The fact that `[1, 2, 3] in d` is True after `d[[1, 2, 3]] = 'a'` in your example suggests you want to compare keys with `==` or something equivalent, but `==` doesn't work on self-nested lists.

Comment: I suspect what you need is either a mapping by identity, or a thorough reexamination of your design decisions.

Comment: @user2357112 The realization that it makes sense for the implementation to be unable to deal with a value that cannot be compared with == without raising a RecursionError is sufficient. abarnet's answer is entirely satisfying.

Comment: @user2357112 mapping by identity obviously would not work for different lists that are equal.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon On further reflection, when comparing `{x: 0} == {y: 0}` (where x and y are distinct self-containing lists), is TOOWTDI to ensure you get the same exception as `{0: x} == {0: y}`? Or whatever would happen if `x` were a self-containing tuple created by the C API? True (for the same reason as hypersets in anti-foundation set theory)? I was trying to get False to work, but that actually seems like the least defensible option, and I’m not sure anymore why that was my first instinct.

Comment: OK, with self-containing tuples, `t == t` returns True, as does `t == (t,)` (because all 1 members of `t` are equal to all 1 members of `(t,)`, but `t == u` raises a `RecursionError`. So that's _not_ what should happen with `x` and `y`, because tuples explicitly check identity first and lists don't (even if the original reason for that is about optimization rather than about mutability).

Comment: Also, `d = {t: 0}` segfaults, which is probably not behavior we'd want to emulate. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason the `deepcopy` technique won't work for you to solve the recursion problem.

What I think you may be missing is that `deepcopy`'s memoization is based on the `id` of the values. You only need to catch objects that contain *themselves*, identically, not objects that contain *equal but distinct* objects. After all, you can't have an infinite depth of distinct but equal objects; that would take infinite memory.

In fact, you can make this simpler than `deepcopy` and `pickle`, because it doesn't really matter *what* you return for a repeated object, as long as it's hashable and unique.<sup>1</sup>

So, for example:

```
def hashable(obj, *, memo=None):
    if memo is None:
        memo = set()
    if id(obj) in memo:
        return (..., id(obj))
    memo.add(id(obj))
    try:
        hash(obj)
        return obj
    except TypeError:
        if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
            return tuple(ForcedHashable.hashable(o, memo=memo) for o in obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, set):
            return frozenset(ForcedHashable(o, memo=memo) for o in obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, dict):
            return frozenset((k, ForcedHashable.hashable(v, memo=memo)) for k, v in obj.items())
        raise
```

And now:

```
>>> x = []
>>> x.append(x)
>>> ForcedHashable.hashable(x)
((Ellipsis, 4658316360),)
>>> d = MutableKeyDict()
>>> d[x] = d
>>> d[x]
{<__main__.ForcedHashable object at 0x115855240>: 2, <__main__.ForcedHashable object at 0x115a247f0>: {...}}
```

While we're at it, do this:

```
elif isinstance(obj, (dict, MutableKeyDict)):
    return frozenset((k, ForcedHashable.hashable(v, memo=memo)) for k, v in obj.items())
```

… and now:

```
>>> d = MutableKeyDict()
>>> d[d] = d
>>> d
{<__main__.ForcedHashable object at 0x11584b320>: {...}}
```

---

<sub>1. Unless you want them to work like Quine atoms, in which case you want it to be hashable and shared by all other Quine atoms of the same type, which is just as easy.</sub>